# Djangoにてデータベースから呼び出したデータをトップページに表示できない

Tags: python, django

現在、Djangoにてデータベースにあるデータをトップページにowlcarousel2で作成したスライダーにforループを回して出力しようとしています。
トップページのtemplateはaccountｓアプリケーション内にあり、表示させたいデータはtournamentアプリケーション内のmodelsにあります。
他のページでは呼び出せているのですが、topページでだけ呼び出せません。

自分で調べてやったことは、settings.pyの見直し、誤字の見直し、テンプレートパスが正しいか確認、テンプレート変数名を修正です。しかし解決せず、そもそもエラーコードが出てこないので手詰まりです。

必要な情報があれば追加します。

**開発環境**
Python 3.8.6
Django 3.2
pipenv

コードは以下の通りです。

tournament/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from tournament.models import Tournament
~
~
~
def carousel(request):
    carousel = Tournament.objects.all().order_by("-TournamentDate")

    context = {
        'carousel': carousel
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', context)
```

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from account.views import CustomEmailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.carousel, name='carousel'),
    # ...
    path('accounts/email/', CustomEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email'),
    # ...
]
```

accounts/templates/accoutns/home.html

```
{% for result in carousel %}
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 320px; margin-right: 25px;">
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="carousel-item__card">
      <img src="/media/{{ result.TournamentImage }}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>{{ result.TournamentName }}</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: 呼び出せない≒表示できないという表現は、この時点の質問文からだとテンプレートのhtmlファイルに対して「divすら出力できていない」「該当項目のdivだけは出力できている」「divやimgも出力できているがブラウザ上での表示がない」などが想像できますが、それぞれで考え方が変わってくるとは思います。
まずは、レスポンスのHTMLを見た上で事象の詳細化をしてみると良いかもしれません。